# Using Unobtrusive JavaScript to Update an Element

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

As you know, when you upgrade from Rails 2 to 3 you replace this:

```
link_to_remote "more", :url => {...}
```

with this:

```
link_to "more", {...}, :remote => true
```

But how do you handle the :update option in link_to_remote? In [Railscast #205](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) Ryan Bates demonstrates `link_to` with `:remote` and a server response that includes JavaScript code to update a particular element in a page, but this practice seems wrong to me. I want my server's response to be a simple HTML fragment which is easy to test and which can be used by different pages (clients) in different ways. I don't think the server should have to know the ID of the target element on the requesting page as it ties the action to the page (a mini-client) and therefore makes it less general (it also feels uglier than a pure HTML response).

So, to be explicit, is there a way to do something like this:

```
link_to_remote "more", :url => {...}, :update => "products-list"
```

with Rails 3 and UJS? Or do I have to write JavaScript to capture the server's HTML response and insert it into the right element on the page?

*If the latter, please describe the best approach (can `link_to`'s `:remote` option be used at all?).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure that this is the Rails-endorsed way to do it, but I've found a solution that works and seems pretty clean. Let's say we have a page that lists the ten most popular products in our database. At the end is a link to load all remaining products via AJAX:

```
<ul id="products-list">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  ...
</ul>
<%= link_to "more...", "/products/all", :id => "load-more", :remote => true %>
```

The server returns plain HTML (so that the link can be used on many different pages and is not bound to particular DOM IDs). We use the `ajax:x` events triggered by the Rails UJS drivers (here I'm using jQuery) to grab the server's response and insert it into the right element on the page:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $("#load-more").bind("ajax:complete", function(et, e){
    $("#products-list").html(e.responseText);
  });
<% end %>
```

If desired, we can also use the `ajax:loading` event to show a "spinner":

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  $("load-more").bind("ajax:loading", function(et, e){
    $(this).hide();
    $("#products-spinner").show();
  });
<% end %>
```

The Rails UJS drivers trigger four other events as well: `ajax:success`, `ajax:failure`, `ajax:before`, and `ajax:after`. See the driver included in your app (public/javascripts/rails.js) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

in the js view `/apps/views/product/index.js.erb` you can write JS code such as the following

prototype:

```
$("products-list").update("<%= escape_javascript(render(@products))%>");
```

jquery:

```
$("products-list").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@products))%>");
```

or

```
$("products-list").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@products))%>");
```

and it will be executed when the request is successful

Comment: This is exactly what I said I don't want to do, because it ties the server's response to an element on the page ("products-list"). That prevents me from using the same URL to update another page where I might want to insert the same content into an element with a different ID.

Comment: so pass the id of the element you want updated to the controller and have it use that in the view

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can apply the latter approach (write custom JS to get server response) by using *link_to :remote*.

you can also choose to get a json response, then update data on the page using JS. in any case, remember to render only the partial, not the entire page.

EDIT:

a sample code, this should make AJAX call when clicking something with id "more", then update a #product-list element in the page:

```
 $("#more").click(function() {
 // make a POST call and replace the content
    $.post(, function(data) {
      $("#products-list").html(data);
    });
  });
```

you don't need more code, and you can write some helper to generate this JS, instead of writing code in the view. btw this is yet UJS

Comment: Can you give some sample code? If I use the `:remote => true` option, how can I capture the server's HTML response and insert it into the page?

Comment: Thanks for the code, but that looks like something I'd use instead of `:remote => true`, or am I missing something? Doesn't `:remote => true` handle the POST/GET request? What I need is a way to intercept the server's response from outside the code that initiates the request (which is in the Rails UJS Prototype or jQuery "driver"). Does this make sense?